# Why am I getting stack smashing detected when doing memcpy?

Tags: c, memory-management

```
    char test[]={"abcde"};
    char* test1={"xyz"};
    memcpy(test+5,test1,3);
    printf("%s",test);
```

I'm trying to grasp how exactly memcpy works and this is the example I've written so far.
This gives output as `abcdexyz&vjunkcharacters`

and the following message.

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./testcode terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x45)[0xb7656dd5]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xffd8a)[0xb7656d8a]
./testcode[0x8048797]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb75704d3]
./testcode[0x80483a1]
```

What are the reasons behind this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Root Cause:**

```
char test[]={"abcde"};
```

Allocates enough memory space to store `5` characters only.

```
memcpy(test+5,test1,3);
```

Copies the data pointed by `test1` beyond the allocated memory space.
Technically, writing beyond the bounds of an allocated memory in this fashion is **Undefined Behavior**, which means anything can happen.

**What actually happens?**

What actually happens here is `memcpy` copies characters beyond the allocated memory thus overwritting the `NULL` terminator which marks ends of your character array `test`.
Further, `printf` reads the contents from starting address of `test` till it encounters a random `NULL` thus printing out junk characters.

**Solution:**
You should ensure that destination buffer has enough memory allocated before you perform the `memcpy`. Since you intend to copy `3` characters, Your destination buffer `test` should be atleast:

```
5 + 3 + 1 byte for NULL terminator = 9 bytes
```

You can simply use:

```
char test[9]="abcde";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `memcpy` call *does* smash the stack, which is why you see that message.  You're copying data past the end of your `test` array, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Then how should I do it, if I want the output as abcdexyz

Comment: Declare `test` as a larger array.

Comment: If I keep this restriction on size, is there a way to still do this correctly.

Comment: and why do I get to see the printf statement output, shouldn't that be halt and be told you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Just because you do something wrong, it doesn't mean that the compiler (or even the runtime) will be able to tell.  You're lucky you're even getting that stack smashing message.

Comment: @gizgok You can print both strings one after the other, separately, without concatenating them in the memory.

Answer (score 2):

**Doing it without an additional buffer**

The most straight-forward approach, indeed, would be to avoid the copy:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char a[] = "abcde";
  char b[] = "xyz";
  printf("%s%s\n", a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

---

**Doing it with memcpy**

memcpy copies `n` bytes from `src` to `dest`. You need to keep track of copying null termination bytes of the strings correctly yourself.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char a[] = "abcde";
  char b[] = "xyz";

  /* note that both strings add a '\0' termination */
  char c[sizeof(a) + sizeof(b) - 1];

  /* copy the content of a to c */
  memcpy(c, a, sizeof(a));

  /* copy the content of b to where a ends (concatenate the strings) */
  memcpy(c + sizeof(a) - 1, b, sizeof(b));

  /* note that the '\0' termination of the string is necessary to let
   * functions like printf know where the string is over 
   */
  printf(c);

  return 0;
}
```

---

**Doing it with strcpy and strcat**

Note that there's a lot of pitfalls dealing correctly with the null termination of the strings when using memcpy. To simplify this procedure for strings you should do the following.

If these are indeed strings and not random bytes you should stick to the string functions of the standard library. This is how it's done.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char a[] = "abcde";
  char b[] = "xyz";

  /* note that both strings add a '\0' termination */
  char c[sizeof(a) + sizeof(b) - 1];

  /* copy the content of a to c */
  strcpy(c, a);

  /* copy the content of b to where a ends (concatenate the strings) */
  strcat(c, b);

  /* note that the '\0' termination of the string is necessary to let
   * functions like printf know where the string is over 
   */
  printf(c);

  return 0;
}
```

---

**On knowing the size of the strings**

Concerning knowing the size of the buffer, note that you can usually not simply do `sizeof(a_string)`. If you pass a character array to a function it decays to a pointer and this operation no longer returns the expected size of the array but the size of the pointer.

For strings you need to issue `strlen(a_string)` which scans for the occurance of the null termination and returns the length of the string (not including the termination).

As for character buffers containing random data (or empty buffers that need to be written to) this approach doesn't work either. You always need to pass the size of the buffer as an additional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The line `memcpy(test+5,test1,3);` does the following in plain words:

"start at the last element of array "test" and copy 3 characters from array "test1" to there", which basically writes 2 characters beyond the length of the array 'test'.

So if you just want to play around with 'memcpy' define a 3rd array:

```
char test[]="abcde";
char test1[]="xyz";
char output[sizeof(test) + sizeof(test1)];
memset(output, 0, sizeof(output));
memcpy(&output[0],test,5);
memcpy(&output[5],test1,3);
printf("%s",output);
```

Comment: You aren't '\0'-terminating `output[]`!

Answer (score 1):

Variable test1 is in memory 4 chars, 3 plus the ending string terminator. Try this:

```
char test[9]={"abcde"};
char* test1={"xyz"};
memcpy(test+5,test1,4);
```

Comment: Those null characters are pretty unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah I know, habitual practice ;-)

Comment: @Carl: Thanks for pointing out. I should change this practice now :-)

Comment: what Carl probably meant is, you should copy the null terminator as well.